# Store specific user input in Watson Assistant in a AWS RDS DB

Tags: ibm-cloud, amazon-rds, watson-assistant

I have created a DB instance using AWS RDS and was successful to connect the DB instance using DBeaver DB Tool. Also, created a simple table with few columns and inserted record in the table using DBeaver.

Now I am trying to develop dialog flow in Watson Assistant skill, where the Bot will ask the user some specific question and the user will provide the answers. The user input may be string or number anything. These inputs should be stored in the external DB like AWS RDS DB table and when user wants he/ she will ask the Bot and the Bot should be able to retrieve the stored data.

In a nutshell, need to create successful integration between Watson Assistant and AWS RDS DB for storing & retrieving the data.

I am quite new to WA and AWS both and hence need to know on how to build up the integration between Watson Assistant and AWS RDS DB and how to store/ retrieve the user inputs (as described above).

Can anyone kindly help me in this regard in detail with specific steps?

Answer (score 0):

There is an IBM Cloud tutorial to hook up [Watson Assistant to a database](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/solution-tutorials?topic=solution-tutorials-slack-chatbot-database-watson) and the [input is available as `$input`](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-expression-language#expression-language-builtin-vars).

To connect to any external data source (except Watson Discovery, see "search skill"), you would need to define a webhook as shown in the linked tutorial. Implement a dispatch function (Cloud Functions, AWS Lambda, IBM Cloud Code Engine, ...) that takes the input and connects to the data source and performs the desired action.

Comment: Thanks much for your input, this will definitely help to enhance my knowledge. I was going through this and found it is more oriented on IBM DB2, IBM Cloud Functions. Can you kindly help with few more links which shows the mechanism to connect WA with AWS RDS DB?

Comment: To be more specific I want to know the points: 1> Option in WA from where I can hit some URL for connection/ insertion of (user input) data into the DB Table in AWS? Is it Webhook in WA?  2> How to create/ configure that URL which can be used to store/ retrieve the data in between WA & AWS RDS DB?

Comment: see my extended answer

Comment: As Henrik mentioned you can replace the DB2 in the example with any database, and the same with the IBM Cloud function. I would recomend that you find an example or tutorial that shows how to interact with the AWS RDS database via a Lambda function, and then understand how to call this function from Watson assistant (just the same as calling an IBM function).